# Rotate labels in a chordDiagram (R circlize)

Tags: r, chord-diagram, circlize

Here is some code from the `circlize` package for creating a chord diagram.Right now the labels are parallel to the edge of the circle.  Is it possible to rotate the labels 90 degrees to they are perpendicular to the circle?

```
library(circlize)
set.seed(999)
mat = matrix(sample(18, 18), 3, 6)
rownames(mat) = paste0("Start", 1:3)
colnames(mat) = paste0("End", 1:6)
chordDiagram(mat)
```

In the figure below I manually inserted a few labels to show what I hope to accomplish (End5, End6, End7).  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: chordDiagram is spelt wrong in this example - in case anyone tries to run this code

Comment: @baxx, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on your example data, here's one way to do it:

```
grid.col <- setNames(rainbow(length(unlist(dimnames(mat)))), union(rownames(mat), colnames(mat)))
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), mfrow = c(1, 2))

# original image
chordDiagram(mat, grid.col = grid.col) 

# now, the image with rotated labels
chordDiagram(mat, annotationTrack = "grid", preAllocateTracks = 1, grid.col = grid.col)
circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 1, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
  xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
  ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
  sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
  circos.text(mean(xlim), ylim[1] + .1, sector.name, facing = "clockwise", niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, 0.5))
  circos.axis(h = "top", labels.cex = 0.5, major.tick.percentage = 0.2, sector.index = sector.name, track.index = 2)
}, bg.border = NA)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is great.  My example show the data in the form of an adjacency matrix.  If my data were in the form of an adjacency list, would I just re-work the `grid.col` variable?

Comment: I just used `grid.col` to fix the choice of colors. Tbh, never used the package, but grabbed the code from the vignette.

Comment: @Brian, Are you using the package with version >=0.3.0? If so, the input variable for `chordDiagram()` now can be an adjacency list and `grid.col` can be set as same as if the input is a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a code example within the official [circlize documentation](https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/advanced-usage-of-chorddiagram.html#customize-sector-labels) to rotate the outer labels:

```
chordDiagram(mat, grid.col = grid.col, annotationTrack = "grid", 
    preAllocateTracks = list(track.height = max(strwidth(unlist(dimnames(mat))))))
# we go back to the first track and customize sector labels
circos.track(track.index = 1, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
    circos.text(CELL_META$xcenter, CELL_META$ylim[1], CELL_META$sector.index, 
        facing = "clockwise", niceFacing = TRUE, adj = c(0, 0.5))
}, bg.border = NA) # here set bg.border to NA is important
```

[image: chord diagram with rotated labels]