# Remove Tick Marks and Numeric Labels from Circlize Chord Diagram

Tags: r, circlize

I'm looking for a way to remove the default "tick marks" and "numeric labels" that appear on a chord diagram made with the R package Circlize. I'm trying to use the package to visualize employees moving from one department to another.
Below is an example of my data, which I store as a data frame (df)

```
 From Department        To Department
        Aviation                  HRD     
             CMO        Neighborhoods     
             CPD          Parks & Rec     
     Conventions      Municipal Court     
         Finance                  Law     
             GSD                  WSD     

library(circlize)
chordDiagaram(df)
```

[image: Image of what this looks like with current code and some additional data]

Any thoughts on how to remove the tick marks that appear around the colored bars as well as the labels "0,1,2"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424421/r-adjusting-labels-in-circlize-diagram

Comment: Thanks @rawr, but I don't understand what part of that code is adjusting that stuff out. sector.name? Ccircos.text? I've read the documentation a few times but it's over my head.

Comment: I think the idea is to build up the plot since the default is to have ticks and there isn't an option to remove them. If you wanted to add them back in manually, you can do something like `circos.axis('bottom')` in the `circos.trackPlotRegion` function

Comment: OP found answer in [Visualize Relations by Chord Diagram](https://web.archive.org/web/20150923114016/https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/circlize/vignettes/visualize_relations_by_chord_diagram.pdf)