# r chord-diagram circlize --> rotating names

Tags: r, plot, rotation, chord-diagram, circlize

I am writing because I would like to get some help with a plot in R, using the package circlize, please.

I am trying to make a chord diagram, and I could make it, but the names on the plot are overlapped,

[image]

then I tried with a code that I picked up from:
and I got the same plot, but with the names repeated, and overlapped on each other [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEk1f.png)

the code that I am using for my plot is

```
chordDiagram(as.matrix(naxo2)
         ,grid.border = 1,
         grid.col = NULL,
         transparency = 0.5,
         preAllocateTracks = 0)
```

and the data frame already has the names included in the matrix that I am using.

what I would like to get is a plot in which the names appear in a 90 degrees to avoid the overlapping.

Any help is very welcome, and thanks in advance!

PS: I also tried the another solution that was posted here, but I did not work for me ([R: Adjusting Labels in circlize diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424421/r-adjusting-labels-in-circlize-diagram?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Comment: Search for D3 charts in R. https://d3js.org/

Comment: Looks that you should use `circos.trackPlotRegion` and use a special `panel.fun` , take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943102/rotate-labels-in-a-chorddiagram-r-circlize).

Comment: You can refer to http://zuguang.de/circlize_book/book/advanced-usage-of-chorddiagram.html#customize-sector-labels

Answer (score 2):

Please next time provide the data needed to reproduce your example.

The idea is to plot the diagram first without labels, and then add the text selecting for the argument `facing` one of the options that rotate the labels, e.g. `clockwise`. Here one example

```
data("cars")

# Clockwise labels may require increasing the canvas margins
circos.par(canvas.xlim=c(-1.5,1.5),canvas.ylim=c(-1.5,1.5))
df.test=df[,c(1,2)]

cDiag = chordDiagram(df.test, 
             #directional = 2, 
             annotationTrack = "grid")

for(si in get.all.sector.index()) {
  xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim", sector.index = si, track.index = 1)
  ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim", sector.index = si, track.index = 1)
  circos.text(mean(xlim),ylim[1], si, sector.index = si, track.index = 1, 
              facing = "clockwise", 
              cex=0.8, 
              adj=c(-1,0),
              niceFacing = TRUE)
  circos.axis(h = 0,
              major.at = c(0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5) ,
              labels.cex = 0.2,labels.facing = "inside", 
              sector.index = si, track.index = 1)
}


circos.clear()
```

[image: chord Diagram clockwise labels]